# How can I add attributes to methods and types defined in IronPython?

Tags: .net, attributes, ironpython

Since IronPython doesn't support attributes I am wondering if there is another way to decorate IronPython classes with attributes, perhaps with reflection?

Answer (score 2):

One, albeit ugly and sometimes impractical, workaround is to create a stub class in C# and decorate it with attributes and derive from that in IronPython.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but clrtype allows you to use attribute.

```
import clr
import clrtype
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import DllImportAttribute
import System

class PInvoke(object):

    __metaclass__ = clrtype.ClrClass
    DllImport = clrtype.attribute(DllImportAttribute)

    @staticmethod
    @DllImport("user32.dll")
    @clrtype.accepts(System.UInt32)
    @clrtype.returns(System.Boolean)
    def MessageBeep(beepType): raise RuntimeError("Something went wrong.")

PInvoke.MessageBeep(0)
```

I'm not sure if it works on classes though.

Comment: In IryonPython 2.6.2 and 2.7 Beta 2, I don't find that clrtype module. Can you give me a hint where it is?

Comment: Can you help me please convert for example this:
`[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo)`
To IronPython that i can understand how it work?